# To create the object using (.) operator and display the

Tags: oop, groovy

```
class Solution{
   static void main(String[] args){
      ("write a code here")
   }
}
// object class
class Car{
   public String Brand = "Honda";
   public int year = 2009;
   public String Model = "City AMT";
}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: a popular ticktocker wants to impress his' subscribers?